# react native - use XIB as loading view and load view controller code as well

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, xcode8

Trying to have an intro video with react native. The method is this:

in AppDelegate.m:

```
  UIView* launchScreenView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadVideoView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
  launchScreenView.frame = self.window.bounds;
  rootView.loadingView = launchScreenView;
  rootView.loadingViewFadeDelay = 5;
```

Then I have these files:
[image]

LoadVideoView is linked to the controller from the 'File's Owner' tab:
[image]

Code within LoadVideo.swift:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class LoadVideo: AVPlayerViewController {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("view did load!!!!!")

    playLocalVideo()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func playLocalVideo() {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "loading 2048", ofType: "mp4")
    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
    //        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.showsPlaybackControls = false

    self.player = player

    self.player!.play()
  }

}
```

Problem is that no code executes in the controller. If I try and add an IBOutlet, it crashes. The XIB/NIB displays, but nothing happens if I log from the controller. How can I get the video to display? (it works fine if I set up a test project and use a storyboard's viewcontroller)

I noticed while writing this question that owner is self in appdelegate. This seems like it should be an instance of the controller, but I'm not really sure what to put there instead.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @shallowThought Hit save before I finished! Have updated it.